# Are type on python's builtin unique

Tags: python, built-in-types

Can I assume that that type objects of python's built ins are always the same?
Example:

```
type([]) == type([1,2,3,4]) == type([{1:1}, True])
type(5) == type(0) == type(2**18) == type(-951)
```

If so, can I use "is" instead of "==" when comparing type objects?
The question is referring to all builtin types.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Checking the types explicitly will reject all subclasses. If you need to do type checking as opposed to duck typing, generally you should use `isinstance` and `issubclass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2:
Generally, yes. However, integers are somewhat of an exception: there's two different types of integers: `int`s and `long`s. The latter is capable of holding integers up to an arbitrary size, whereas the former can only hold integers between `-2**31` to `2**31-1`.

So, for example, `type(3) is type(2**50)` will return `False`. However, it would return `False` just the same if you used `==` instead of `is`.

Comment: Great, Thank you for your comment

Comment: Python 2 `int` is based on a C `long`. On Windows that's always the `-2**31` to `2**31-1` range that you mentioned, but on 64-bit Linux the range is `-2**63` to `2**63-1`, and your example doesn't work. In general, you should reference the `int` range as `-sys.maxint - 1` to `sys.maxint`. Python 3 is simpler; there's only a single `int` type, which is basically the `long` type renamed as `int`.